# why I need to pass a function in return statement in handler of onChange event

Tags: reactjs

[image]
Problem in onchange event Handler. You can see output of this code in second photo. Already 8 time event fired without change any checkbox.
[image]
Out Put of this code is here[image]
When I Used return Function in handler and click on any check box its worked expectedly
?????

[image]
You can see only one time event fired . what is the reason behind it ???

Answer (score 0):

To work properly you need to use below input tag

`<input onChange={()=>handler()} type="checkbox">`

or

`<input onChange={handler} type="checkbox">`

If you use onChange={handler()} then you are calling the handler method at every render.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `onChange={handler}` and not `onChange={handler()}`.
This applies to other similar functions as well like
`<button onClick={handleClick} />`.

Since here you're using onChange, and you will require **event** for onChange, here's what your need to do

`<input onChange={(event)=>handler(event)} />`

`const handler = (event) => { ...//use the event here }`